# Full Screen Navigation Overlay with Icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner HTML/CSS Coder, learning how to code. I needed some help in creating a full screen navigation. Here is the design file: [Menu Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DK6Rn.png)

W3Schools give an idea as to the approach to make the Full Screen overlay, but I am still a bit perplexed.

Can someone tell me how to approach this. The white boxes in image (2) are icons. I am a little stuck on how the icons should be placed and how the menu can go across the whole screen.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: have you tried anything so far. If so please post the code here

Comment: No I have not. I just want a general direction to create that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you check out flex box by playing the game [flex froggy](http://flexboxfroggy.com/)
You can wrap the middle section links inside a div and use flex row to spread it out and then justify-content to add space between each element.

check out this 
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2yetsmnj/).

```
<div class="links">
  <a href="">Link 1</a>
  <a href="">Link 2</a>
  <section>
    <a href="">Link 3</a>
    <a href="">Link 4</a>
    <a href="">Link 5</a>
    <a href="">Link 6</a>
  </section>
</div>

section {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex! I also want to know how to hide the menu and then show it when a button is clicked.

Comment: You can check out https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Fiddle if you want the same example
https://jsfiddle.net/2yetsmnj/3/

Comment: <div class="homepage-menu-open-icon">
     <a class="closebtn" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="closeNav()">
     <div class="homepage-menu-open" onclick="myFunction(this)">
      <div class="bar1"></div>
      <div class="bar2"></div>
      <div class="bar3"></div>
     </div></a>

Comment: Is it possible to use a cross animation. I have created it.

Comment: .bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
    width: 40px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 6px 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
    border: 2%;
}

.change .bar1 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px) ;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-6px, 6px) ;
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px) ;
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-7px, -8px) ;
}

Comment: That includes the HTML and CSS